# unable to debug a node script after sending it the USR1 signal

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I'm playing around with node-inspector, and trying to figure out how to debug an already running process.  The method, as I understand it, is to send it a USR1, but this doesn't seem to be working for me.  Here's what I'm doing:

- I have a simple script that sits in an infinite loop and prints out a number every half a second
- I run that script using `node infinite.js`
- I determine the process via `ps x | grep infinite`
- I send the process a USR1 via `kill -s USR1 2079`
- I refresh my node-inspector page and get ECONNREFUSED.

If I run my script with `node --debug infinite.js` I can debug fine.  Is there something obvious I'm missing?  Is there some easy way to validate within my script whether it's properly receiving the USR1 signal?

Comment: What version of node.js are you using? When you send USR1 signal, does the node process print `debugger listening on port 5858`?

Comment: v0.10.12.  Node does not print anything about debugger listening when I send the USR1 signal.

Comment: In that case, you are most likely sending the signal to a wrong process.

Comment: That is not the case. I've successfully killed the process with no signal specified, and also with a USR2 signal. However, for some reason it seems that node is ignoring my USR1 signal.